# Is it possible the use headless mode with 'Remote Driver Config' for selenium jmeter plugin

Tags: selenium, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm following https://www.swtestacademy.com/performance-testing-jmeter-selenium-grid/ document and I'm trying to use chrome browser in headless mode with the Selenium Grid.

I dont find an option in 'Remote Driver Config' sampler to do that. How can I set up headless mode for remote driver? ( I'm planning to use selenium grid)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're "following" an external resource you should ask the question there, not here.
2. As of [WebDriver Sampler 3.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/3.3) it is not possible, if you want to continue "following" the article you will have to switch to the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) where you will have the full freedom of initializing the [RemoteWebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html) and passing `--headless` and whatever else arguments you want to it.
3. As per [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/test_practices/discouraged/performance_testing/):

   > Performance testing using Selenium and WebDriver is generally not advised. Not because it is incapable, but because it is not optimised for the job and you are unlikely to get good results.
4. As per [WebDriver Sampler documentation](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/):

   > Note: It is NOT the intention of this project to replace the HTTP Samplers included in JMeter. Rather it is meant to compliment them by measuring the end user load time.

so it looks like "following" the document is not the best idea and you should reconsider your approach